# Hyperplane arrangements - numbering regions by "regional distance" from a line

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Consider the following statement (contrived to highlight an unknown piece of terminology):

> For any $n$-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$, a finite number of
> $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes in a general arrangement will separate
> $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a finite number of $n$-dimensional regions. Let
> $d_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ be region $i$'s "regional distance" from a
> reference line (that is, of course, $1$ dimensional). The reference
> line can be assumed not to be a subset of any of the hyperplanes.

By "regional distance" I mean the minimum number of $n$-dimensional regions that need to be "traversed" to get from any point on the line to a point in the given region, where $d_i = 0$ if region $i$ intersects the reference line. Obviously I have not defined "regional distance" well, but I expect it has a term (or there is a term for a very similar concept) that I'm unaware of. What I hope is that someone reading this knows the right term for me to google.

To illustrate

[image: this figure]

which shows $d_i$ for all regions, for an example $n=2$ case. As shown, any region that is adjacent to a region that intersects the reference line has "regional distance" 1, and any region that is adjacent to a region that is adjacent to a region that intersects the reference line has "regional distance" 2.

EDIT: Fixed error in image.

Comment: Apologies if the link doesn't work. Apparently imgur is currently down...

Comment: Something similar has probably been named many times. "regional distance" might even be among them. But this isn't something that arises often enough for there to be a commonly recognized name. You are free to give it whatever name you like.